# pass a variable to html page in Angular2js / Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, angular

I have a dart class write in this way:

```
@Component(selector: 'my-content', templateUrl: '../../views/example.html', directives: const [NgFor, NgIf, NgStyle, NgClass], pipes: const [LowerCasePipe, JoinByPipe])

class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
@Input()
 ContentComponent(@Inject(ContentService) this.contentService, @Inject(LoggerService) this.log) {

  }

  @override
  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.className = '.Ciao';
  }
```

In **example.html** I do this

```
  <span class="pull-right channel"   [ngClass]="{className}">some content</span>
```

When I build this project I take this message:

```
<span class="pull-right channel"   [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{className}">some content</span>
```

which is the correct syntax?

Comment: `@Inject(ContentService)` and `@Inject(LoggerService)` are redundant if the fields have the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax directive:

```
<span class="pull-right channel" [ngClass]="{Ciao:ciaoClass}">some content</span>
```

and

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.ciaoClass = true;
}
```

If `ciaoClass` is true, the class is added and if it's false, it will be removed...

You can also provide an array (or a string delimited with spaces) to `[ngClass]` corresponding to all classes you want to set.

```
<span class="pull-right channel" [ngClass]="className">some content</span>
```

and

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.className = [ 'Ciao' ];
  // or
  // this.className = 'Ciao';
}
```

See this documentation:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html